# How do I get to the SecurityTokenHandlers collection in WIF 4.5?

Tags: .net, wif, .net-4.5

I am migrating an ASP.Net site that uses Active Federation and WIF 3.5 to use .Net 4.5. The functionality of Windows Identity Foundation (WIF 3.5) has now been fully integrated in into the .Net 4.5 Framework.

Since classes have moved to three different namespaces, it is mostly a matter of mechanical translation. The part that I am having trouble with is translating the `GenericXmlSecurityToken` issued by the STS to a Claims Principal for the call to `SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie`. The documentation is lacking and I just need to find the WIF 4.5 way to access `FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers`

Here is a snippet of the WIF 3.5 code that does not compile in WIF 4.5 (WSTrust channel creation omitted for brevity):

```cs
var genericToken = channel.Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;

var handlers = FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;

var token = handlers.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(genericToken.TokenXml.OuterXml)));
var identity = handlers.ValidateToken(token).First();

var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(ClaimsPrincipal.CreateFromIdentity(identity),
                                            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));

FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fix turned out to be fairly simple (If not immediately obvious).

```cs
FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers
```

translates to WIF 4.5 as

```
FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers
```

The only other change was replacing the `ClaimsPrincipal.CreateFromIdentity(identity)` factory method call with `new ClaimsPrincipal(identity)`.

Below is the working snippet:

```cs
var handlers = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;

var token = handlers.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(genericToken.TokenXml.OuterXml)));
var identity = handlers.ValidateToken(token).First();

var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                                            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));

FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
```

Comment: `FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers` - What is ***namespace*** and ***assembly*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet `System.IdentityModel.Services`, which is a separate assembly